# Design To Handle Multiple Similar Model Class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am doing a web app for an event company whereby customer can access the website for a self-help instant quotation. Customer will choose the type of event, fill a form and expect an instant quotation.

Can anyone give me some tips how can I improve my design? Below are my current design thoughts.

Quotation class:

```
public class Quotation{

    // Customer specific details
    private String customerName;
    private String customerEmail;
    private String customerMobile;

    // Event specific details
    private WeddingEvent weddingEvent;
    private RetreatEvent retreatEvent;
    // ... another 4 or 5 more event classes

    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

Event Classes:

```
public class BaseEvent{
    private int attendance;
    private String venue;
}

public class WeddingEvent extends BaseEvent{
    private boolean needWeddingPlanner;
    // getters and setters
    // ...
}

public class RetreatEvent extends BaseEvent{
    private boolean needBreakfast;
    private boolean needLunch;
    private boolean needDinner;

    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish, in what way are you **using** these classes?

Comment: Hi Simon, these are domain classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following potential improvements.

Change the Quotation class to the following

```
public class Quotation
{
    private Customer customer;

    private List<BaseEvent> events = new List<BaseEvent>();


    // Getters and setters to access the two entities above.
}
```

So now you have divided you elements into specific entities like Quotation, Customer and Events.

Adding more details to a Customer or adding a new Event type, don't require change to the Quotation class, but only changes to the specific entity.

On the side, you might also find it beneficial to look into a simple visitor pattern for the events and provide algorithms to etc. calculate total price, date collisions, number of participants etc. etc.

Enjoy.

Comment: Really appreciate the pointers. May I ask further.. if I do a BaseEvent event = new RetreatEvent(), can I do a event.getNeedBreakfast() method? I tried it but I realised I couldn't call getNeedBreakfast() method. Not sure if I am missing out anything.

Comment: Having a collection of BaseEvent's only allow you to call the methods that you expose on the BaseEvent class or an IBaseEvent interface.

Comment: So those methods will be pretty generic. You might have a Show() method on the IBaseEvent, that all events will implement. Does that help you.

Comment: thanks man. That means i have to do a cast if I need to call methods in the child yea?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, but I normally try to prevent doing type cast's as it can indicate a problem with the design and the layering of the application. The motor/logic of the code should typically not need to know about specific event types. You might implement different renderes, repositories and logic components to support each event type. It might seem like overkill, but as you application gets larger and the logic more complex, it might not be a bad choice to go this way.

Comment: Thanks @andershybertz! Just to double confirm.. so you are saying that I could implement different renderers or logic components to access the class-specific methods such as the `WeddingEvent.needWeddingPlanner()` and `RetreatEvent.needBreakfast()` right?

Comment: Yip - dedicated logic will know all the event details, properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointers! Really appreciate it. =)